# Package fat jar into a debian using sbt native packaging

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

On running "sbt debian:packageBin" command, the fakeroot program fails since it tries to look for the fat jar (assembly) in /target dir instead of /target/scala-2.11/ directory.

So, is there a setting to specify the source directory for debian packaging using sbt Debian plugin?

SBT version: 0.13.11
Added below in plugins.sbt:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.4")

In build.sbt, have added below:
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(DebianPlugin)

Comment: Thanks for your question. Could you add a bit more information: sbt, assembly and native-packager version, `build.sbt`

Comment: Edited the question, updated with the versions for sbt, native-packager and build.sbt snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing a few things up here.
SBT native-packager and sbt-assembly solve both the same problem ( creating something you can deploy ), but in different ways.

### how to fix your issue with native-packager

Check out the [installation section in the reader](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/README.md#installation), which states:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackacking)
```

This configures your build to create JVM application packages. You can now run `sbt Debian:packageBin`.

### sbt assembly

You'll have to create the debian package yourself. Assembly only generates a fat jar.

Cheers,
Muki